# Serializar a JSON con C#

Tags: c#, json

Estoy intentando serializar un objeto que lleva internamente otros objetos con diferentes propiedades, pero al crear el archivo solo me muestra los atributos principales `nombre y ubicacion`, en cambio no aparece `dispositivo`, que se encuentra en una `List<Dispositivo>` con el resto de información que hay dentro de esta...
Al mirar dentro del objeto veo que `dispositivos` tiene un candado. ¿Tengo algún problema de acceso a estos? He probado a establecer las clases Dispositivo y Tipo como `Public` pero el problema lo sigo teniendo igual...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clase `Estacion` es la siguiente, la lista la tengo privada porque no quiero que se modifique desde fuera, a no ser que se utilizen sus metodos... ¿Puedo hacer algo para seguir teniendola privada pero que mediante el JSON vea sus propiedades?

```
    namespace Proyecto
    {
       class Estacion
       {
           private string _nombre, _ubicacion;
           private List<Dispositivo> dispositivos = new List<Dispositivo>();

           public string nombre
           {
               get { return _nombre; }
               set { _nombre = value; }
           }

           public string ubicacion
           {
               get { return _ubicacion; }
               set { _ubicacion = value; }
           }

           public List<Dispositivo> getDispositivos()
           {
               return this.dispositivos;
           }

           public void añadirDispositivo(Dispositivo dispositivo)
           {
               this.dispositivos.Add(dispositivo);
           }

           public void eliminarDispositivo(Dispositivo dispositivo)
           {
               this.dispositivos.Remove(dispositivo);
           }
       }
  }
```

Comment: supongo no estas haciendo correctamente el encapsulamiento de tu clase, puedes poner el código de tu clase estaciones?, es con la que parece estas teniendo problemas

Comment: no vas puedes acceder a la atributo de dispositivos, porque no esta accesible mediante una propiedad sino por una función getDispositivos()

Comment: Y que me recomiendas? El caso es que me gustaría guardar el contenido de todos los objetos que cree para poder abrir esa configuración por ejemplo al día siguiente y seguir teniendo esa información. Es por eso lo del JSON, acepto consejos si está solución no es la correcta jeje

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La serializacion solo aplica a las propiedades, no a los metodos, ni las variables privadas

Si quieres que se serialice dispositivos deberias agregar la propiedad publica

```
class Estacion
{
    private string _nombre, _ubicacion;

    public List<Dispositivo> dispositivos { get; set; }

    public Estacion()
    {
        dispositivos = new List<Dispositivo>();
    }

    //resto

}
```

Ademas la inicializacion deberias realizarla en el constructor de la clase

Comment: Si, lo he probado, entonces no me vale esa solución... ¿Alguna idea? Como decía en la respuesta anterior, me gustaría guardar la información de todos los objetos que voy creando y poder abrirla al día siguiente, por ejemplo, es por eso la idea del JSON, lo que intento es tener diferentes archivos con información diferente, como si fuesen archivos asociados a configuraciones. ¿Me recomiendas hacerlo de otra manera?

Comment: porque no resuelve el problema usar una propiedad publica ? porque si lo haces de esta forma tiene que serializar

Answer (score 0):

añadiendo a la respuesta anterior:

si no haces una propiedad publica de tu lista entonces no podrás hacer nada

```
public List<Dispositivo> PublicDispositivos    
{
    get{return Dispositivos;}
    set{Publicdispositivos = value;}
}
```